# TableViewController / Custom cell - can't move to next text field

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view controller with a custom cell which contains a text field - it's a form basically.

i want to automatically go to the next text field when users press "return" on their keyboard but for some reason my solution doesn't work.

In TableViewController, I do:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell
    cell?.box.tag = indexPath.row
```

In my custom table view cell, I have

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    box.delegate = self
    ...
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if let nextField = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag+1) as? UITextField {
        nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

The issue is that textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag+1) is always nil. I don't know why because I clearly set the tag and also mark it as a delegate. thank you.

Comment: Are all the text fields in the same cell?

Comment: yes correct, same cell being reused with different content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some clarity and more suggestions to the **valid** answer by @jawadAli, as I feel you are still new to iOS development.

You are trying to get the `tableView` from the textField. But you will not get it by referring to the **superview** of textField. Because the view hierarchy would be like this:

UITableView > UITableViewCell > contentView > Your text field.

There can also be some more views in the view hierarchy, so you need to keep traversing through the superview chain till you get the `UITableView`. And @jawadAli has posted the code on how to get it.

But overall that is an incorrect approach. You should use **delegation**. I.e. your cell should call a method when it has resigned as first responder. And your table view controller will receive that call.

Then your view controller has to get the next cell and make it the first responder.

And if this doesn't make any sense to you, then I would very strongly suggest that you learn about Delegation. It's ubiquitous in iOS' libraries.

**EDIT:**

Approach to use delegation.

Create a protocol, let's say `CellDelegate` that has a function like `func didFinishDataCapture(forCell: UITableViewCell)`.

The cell will have a `delegate` property of type `CellDelegate`.

The controller will conform to `CellDelegate` and will set itself as the cell's delegate in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Now in your cell, when you are done with the text field (which you would know as cell would be the text field's delegate), you call your own delegate's function i.e. `delegate.didFinishDataCapture(forCell: self)`.

In your implementation of `didFinishDataCapture` in the controller, you will know which cell has finished with the data capture and can put the logic on what to do next.

Comment: hey thanks for the comment. i did try using delegation but to no avail. i am also using UITextFieldDelegate - shouldn't that do this for me?for example, in my table view controller : i set cell?.delegate = self and then had put some logic in func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath). but this did not work.

i agree with you that this is cleaner - can you please put a code snippet to give an example? that would help a lot.

Comment: If I can understand correctly, you tried to set the UITextFieldDelegate as the controller. Which means that controller is the delegate of all the text fields in all the cells. The problem with this is that how would you get the cell associated to a table view unless you maintain a mapping between the text fields and the cells. This approach is not the right one. Posting the right approach in my answer. See the EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

It should be nil as textField.superview is your cell class ... and your cell class does not have the view with required Tag .. so it will return nil..

```
import UIKit
  extension UIView {
    func lookForSuperviewOfType<T: UIView>(type: T.Type) -> T? {
        guard let view = self.superview as? T else {
            return self.superview?.lookForSuperviewOfType(type: type)
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Get tableView through this extension like this

```
let tableView = self.view.lookForSuperviewOfType(type: UITableView.self)
```

your function will become

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let tableView = self.view.lookForSuperviewOfType(type: UITableView.self)
    if let cell = tableView?.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: textField.tag+1, section: 0)) as? CustomCell {
        cell.box.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
         textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
      return true
    }
```